# Pandas timeseries: avg of a timestamp column

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe, which look like this:

```
ID      Date
16911   2017-04-15
16911   2017-04-25
16911   2017-04-27
16911   2017-05-08
16911   2017-05-20
16911   2017-05-25
16911   2017-08-08
16911   2017-08-11
16911   2017-08-24
16912   2017-04-15
16912   2017-04-25
16812   2017-04-27
16812   2017-05-08
16812   2017-05-20
16812   2017-05-25
16812   2017-08-08
16812   2017-08-11
```

the date is sorted, i want to find the diff between the timestamps and find the average for each ID.

also,

suppose for ID - 16911, i want the date difference list for eg -> list a;

```
16911   2017-04-15
16911   2017-04-25
difference between the above two dates is 10, so a is
a = [10]

16911   2017-04-25
16911   2017-04-27
difference between the above two dates is 2, so a is
a=[10,2]

16911   2017-04-27
16911   2017-05-08
difference between the above two dates is 11(assuming), so a is
a=[10,2,11]
```

so the final output should be:

```
ID      Average_Day Diff
16911   3 days      [10,2,11]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) and `mean`:

```
df = df.groupby('ID')['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.diff().mean()).reset_index()
print (df)
      ID             Date
0  16812 21 days 04:48:00
1  16911 16 days 09:00:00
2  16912 10 days 00:00:00
```

If need convert timedeltas, e.g. to `days`:

```
df = df.groupby('ID')['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.diff().mean().days).reset_index()
print (df)
      ID  Date
0  16812    21
1  16911    16
2  16912    10
```

EDIT:

```
#create difference column per ID
df['new'] = df.groupby('ID')['Date'].diff().dt.days
#remove NaT rows (first for each group)
df = df.dropna(subset=['new'])
#convert to integers
df['new'] = df['new'].astype(int)
#aggreagte lists and mean
df = df.groupby('ID', sort=False)['new'].agg([('val', lambda x: x.tolist()),('avg', 'mean')])
print (df)

ID                                          
16911  [10, 2, 11, 12, 5, 75, 3, 13]  16.375
16912                           [10]  10.000
16812             [11, 12, 5, 75, 3]  21.200
```

Comment: i have another question, for each id, can i get the difference of between two dates and store it in a list (for each id, of course) ?

Comment: @SriramArvindLakshmanakumar - Can you add expected output to question?

Comment: i have added the output in the question.